# Aligning items inside a button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a triangle next to written text in a button using only HTML and CSS. For the life of me, I can remember how.

```css
.room-info-btn {
  background-color: #FFA500;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 11px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <button class="room-info-btn" id="room-info-btn">
    <div class="arrow-down"></div> 
    Rooms / Availability
  </button>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try display: inline-table; in arrow-down class to align with the text

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the best solution. Why not flexbox ?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend checking out [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

For your code, you can simply add the following css to your `.room-info-btn` selector:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

This makes aligning many items very simple and gives you other flex control options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Flexbox is a better choice I guess. 
Take a look here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.room-info-btn {
  background-color: #FFA500;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 11px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <button class="room-info-btn" id="room-info-btn">
    <div class="arrow-down"></div> 
    Rooms / Availability
  </button>
</li>
```